# Bing - ignore subdomains?

Tags: seo, subdomain, bing

Let's say my company's site is www.company.com. If you search our company name in Bing, you get results for pages on www.company.com, but some results have a URL that includes a subdomain like "blog.company.com/somepage" instead of the default "www". I believe in Google Webmaster tools you can tell the search engine to see "*.company.com" as being the same as "www.company.com", but I can't seem to find a similar option in Bing's Webmaster Tools.

**Edit:**
Just to be clear, the correct URL for the page is "www.company.com/somepage", but for some reason it's showing up in Bing as "blog.company.com/somepage". Also, this problem is happening in Bing, but not in Google - which is why I'm asking if there's something I need to fix in Bing's webmaster tools.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: I did tag the question as "SEO", which is a pre-existing tag. Is there another area of the site where I should be posting SEO-related questions?

Answer (score 0):

www and without www is actually a redirect (301) which has been set up typically on hosting configuration. But incase of "blog.company.com/somepage" i assume you dont want to redirect so best thing to do is include these pages in your site map, based on bing search criteria it will show up. its not a technical problem as far as i can see..

Comment: Actually, I do want to redirect. The correct URL for the page is "www.company.com/somepage", but it's showing up in Bing as "blog.company.com/somepage".

Comment: That means the page "blog.company.com/somepage". has already been indexed, Now if you have already put the redirection in place then bing will eventually correct itself. If you haven't done the redirection yet and you want to then put a 301 redirect, then keep the actual URLs not "blog.company.com/somepage". on your sitemap. Search results will correct itself.